# STContains on SQL Server vs ST_Contains on PostGIS

Tags: postgis, shapefile, polygon, sql-server, point-in-polygon

I am trying to run a basic point in polygon query against a table of polygons. In PostGIS this works:

```
SELECT *
FROM schema.table
WHERE ST_Contains(
  table.geom,
  ST_PointFromText('POINT(XXX.XXXXXXX YY.YYYYYY)',4283)
);
```

As I understand it, this is the equivalent in SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
FROM schema.table
WHERE column.STContains(
  geography::STPointFromText('POINT(XXX.XXXXXXX YY.YYYYYY)',4283)
) = 1;
```

Both tables are generated from exactly the same shapefile. For PostGIS I use shp2pgsql and for SQL Server I use ogr2ogr to convert the data. In SQL Server I need to run a query to MakeValid the 8 errors in the source data (confirmed in QGIS).

When I run the above query in PostGIS I am returned a single, correct polygon. When I run the other query in SQL Server I am returned a set of polygons, none of which is correct.

Can someone assist me in getting the query correct for SQL Server?

Comment: Can you give us an example with a reduced use case? Perhaps with just the the row PostGIS returns and a row that SQL Server returns? It hard to tell what Microsoft is doing from a pseudocode example.

Comment: Here's the export from [SQL Server](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13pgV1N6Wr2IlnkL4P5xyUkvWGG3VIjN4/view) and the export from [PostGIS](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13zHk0WTonIjGyGAXq8r5nTDP1igKcCIh/view).
The full PostGIS query is 
    SELECT * 
    FROM public.electorates 
    WHERE 
    ST_Contains(
        electorates.geom, 
        ST_PointFromText('POINT(151.0424707 -33.7395596)',4283)
    );

Comment: Is the table using EPSG:4283? Remember that SQL Server doesn't support coordinate transformation

Comment: Yes, the table is using EPSG:4283. I have also used ogr2ogr to reproject to EPSG:4326 when performing the input with the same net result.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of figured it out. Looks like it is a problem in geography vs geometry. If I import the polygons as geometries then it works properly.